# laravel with codeception unitTesting : can't check return echo when using assertEquals()

Tags: php, laravel-5, codeception

## environment

- laravel 5.0.33
- codeception 2.0.16

`App/helpers.php`

```
function sample($message)
{
  echo $message;
}
```

`tests/herpersTest.php`

```
function testsample()
{
  $this->assertEquals('○○○○',sample('test'));
}
```

I want to check echo, but i cant check echo and print.

I know only return check.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo` doesn't return anything so you can't run a test like that. If you want to test if something is printed on to the page you can use the test facilities provided by Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing or you can use the Laravel module in codeception which provides a `see` method: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the output with output buffering functions.

```
function testSample()
{
  ob_start();
  sample('test');
  $output = ob_get_clean();
  $this->assertEquals('○○○○', $output);
}
```